# Cant do a crosspage postback because .aspx is missing from my page names

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, cross-page-posting

In my current project which is quite large, I am missing my page extensions when visiting my pages in my browser. I created a fresh Web Forms project and it works just fine.

Without page extensions I can not do cross page postbacks.

How do I turn extensions on or off? Is this done on the webconfig, IIS express, or my browser?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "missing my page extensions"?

Comment: in my web browser I see localhost:61704/WebForm1.aspx for my working project. In my broken project I only see localhost:61704/WebForm1

By broken I mean that I cant do cross page posts because WebPage2.aspx doesnt see WebPage1.aspx it sees "WebPage1"

Comment: I think you should post your code showing where you're doing the crosspage postback. I suspect you just need to type the extension in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FriendlyUrls was the issue. Removed in via nuget.